# KOMA-Script: How to control the position of title with respect to top margin?

Tags: titles, koma-script, scrbook

Here, I would like to put the title just below the top margin, so how can I remove or change such skip?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=4cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \title{TITLE}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm short in time, so only some hints: Use a custom title (using `titlepage` environment) instead of the predefined one. Or use an in-page title (option `titlepage=false`) instead of a title page. Or use option `titlepage=firstiscover` to define the first title page of `\maketitle` to be a cover page and use the cover page setup commands to define the margins of this page (see `scrguien.pdf` for more information).

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for your suggestions. I would be grateful if you could provide me with compilable answers since I tried to do this on my own, but I failed somehow in case of `titlepage` environment solution.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907

Comment: \maketitle is completely overrated if you are doing a one time only thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the default title pages I would recommend to build a custom title using `titlepage` environment, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=4cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \huge\textsf{\textbf{TITLE}}
  \bigskip

  \normalsize \today
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Johannes answer to "How to customize my titlepage?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907) for more suggestions.

But if you really just want to remove the initial vertical skip you could also patch `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=4cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\null\vfill}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \title{TITLE}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]